# how to save an users vote on a comment to mysql via php?

Tags: php, mysql, user-interface

How to save an users vote on a particular comment? For example if someone likes a comment posted on the site he/she will click the (+) button or other way will click the (-) button.
How could i save this information to mysql, so that when the user come back to the site I can show his/her vote on the comment? Something like facebook comment like system. Should i create a new mysql table to record them all? Assuming the user is already registered user.

my current comment table

```
id | date | userid | page | comment |
```

I expect something like

```
$username - $date
$comment <no.of likes> likes, <no.of hates> hates.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing a many-to-many relationship. You will need an intermediate table between users and comments, since any user can vote on any comment, and any comment can have votes from any users. It might be something like this:

`user_id | comment_id | direction`

If you don't need to store any data about who voted on what, then you can just add a `score` column to your comments table, that gets either increased or decreased whenever a user votes. You can also do both, if you want to quickly get the score of the comments as they're being displayed, but retain the information of who voted on what for later.

edit:

As an after thought, you might want to avoid the `score` column. You might run into a situaion where a single user can vote on a comment more than once, if you don't keep track of which comments that user has already voted on.

Comment: is there's any other ways of doing it? like storing users id and vote as json string in the same comment table? i know this would worsen the condition..

so with your way of doing it as you mentioned above, how could i join the table and could get the user's name instead of userid?
I know theres a method called join mysql, but its really hard to understand for me as a student.

Comment: I dont want a user vote on a comment multiple times, meaning once he/she voted the vote saved and then when the user comeback to the same comment, they can change their votes (overwriting instead of adding)

Comment: how could i join the user_id from the intermediate table with the username in the account table?

Comment: its okay, as long as i can still  read it...alots of thanks to all of you